# Trying to create a virtual topology using miniedit that should use mqtt traffic

Tags: virtual-machine, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, mininet

i have to create a virtual topology with miniedit that has to talk using the mqtt sub/pub system.

i'm working on virtualbox (mininet-wifi)
i have installed mosquitto & the clients... using the terminals i have no problem with:

```
mosquitto_sub -t test

mosquitto_pub -t test -m hello!
```

but when i emulate the topology on Miniedit with (controller,switch and two hosts), the hosts cannot talk using mosquitto, i think that there is no broker that can handle the communications in the virtual topology, any suggestions?

I tried to connect also to a remote server, using cloudmqtt but i only got failed connection

i expect that using

`xterm h1 h2`

on the Comand Line Interface of miniedit, i would be capable of make the two hosts talks beetween them using
mosquitto_sub/pub system, because also in the xterm of the host, if i type

`service mosquitto status`

i obtain that

`mosquitto is active`

UPDATE
solved.
i just have to run another host in which i type "mosquitto" and the others hosts would just reach it using "mosquitto_sub/pub - h 10.0.0.3 for example

Answer (score 0):

2 brokers (1 on each hosts) won't automatically discover each other when the "link" comes up.

You will have to either manually configure the a bridge between the 2 brokers if you want messages to be shared.

Or pick one and have the clients explicitly connect to that one broker. e.g. the `-h` option for the `mosquitto_pub` or `mosquitto_sub` commands.

Comment: ok thank you, but in my topology, i don't have the broker. I just got 2 hosts, 1 switch and 1 controller, on xterm of the host1 if i type "service mosquitto status" seems to work, it's online, but when i try to do "mosquitto_sub -h "what ip i need to use?"

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: Mosquitto is the broker. If you are just running one broker then the client on the other host needs to know the IP address (or a hostname) for the host with the broker.

Comment: but how can i assign the broker funcionalities to an host? Cause i've got a message of "Error connection"

Look:
[Screenshot of the issue](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/6967/SnSmAr.png)

Comment: Edit the original question if you have more information (and post the text of the error message not an image)

Comment: sorry but it seems more efficient to make you see what's the problem i've got, maybe i didn't describe it very well! How can i reach, with an host, a server for example cloudmqtt to solve this problem and have an online broker? i can try this solution?

Comment: EDIT THE QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution. Let me give more in depth explanation.
Run basic mininet topo with 4 hosts and 4 switches.

```
mn --topo linear,4
```

Then open xterm for 3 hosts

```
xterm h1 h2 h3
```

Three terminals will pop up. One of them will be the host. on h3's(10.0.0.3) xterm terminal run

```
mosquitto
```

On h2(10.0.0.2) subscribe to the topic with;

```
mosquitto_sub -h 10.0.0.3 -t "home/bedroom/light"
```

On h1(10.0.0.1) publish a message by;

```
mosquitto_pub -h 10.0.0.3 -t "home/bedroom/light" -m "ON"
```

You can now see the message on h2's terminal. Hope it helps.